# Is autofs the only open-source choice for mounting nfs and/or cifs

Tags: automounting, autofs, cifs

I've been using autofs for a number of years and was wondering if there is an alternative to autofs that would handle cifs/smb shares in a more interactive way?

When I say more interactive I'm mostly referring to allowing interactivity for password authentication (and not keeping your password in a file)?

Comment: Curious, how would you expect this to work? Where would you see the password prompt - gui? command line? Autofs intercepts at kernel-level, something would have to be listening in userland to show you a password dialog, right?

Comment: I'm a command line geek, so my thought was command line - but I guess you've got a point. Not having done much developing besides scripting, how difficult would it be to modify Autofs to send out an event to userland? then I assume it would be easy to create a user app to listen for that event...

Comment: These days, one would probably use the `dbus` (to make it platform neutral) or a unix socket (much less bloat, more work) - you could have clients for command line as well as for various DEs. `automount` daemon (which is already running in userspace) would then send a password request to listening clients and wait for reply.

Comment: Thanks @peterph I was thinking dbus but sockets might be good as well. Any good references for dbus and automount?